# Get cursor type in java

Tags: java, types, cursor, system

I ask you to please suggest me how to get the current system cursor type

For example, I run my application in java, and if I move the cursor over a link on a web page i have open, my application should be able to tell me that the current cursor is a hand.

Thank you all, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Your question is so weird, would you explain a little more? doesn't mouse events help?

Comment: Hi, what I want is to know how to get the cursor type, even if the mouse is not on the application. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you can get the cursor type(at least in java) while the cursor type is customizable. but you can get the mouse position with `MouseInfo`. so generally why are you trying to do this?

Comment: It is an application for remote control,

I can control the mouse of the remote pc but also want that when the cursor of this change, it detects that the pc taking control.

I'll make some more tests, but I manage to fix it, I will try with other technologies.

If I have success, I will share the solution.

Comment: Nice try, but I'm interested how does the mouse type would be informative? it's highly recommended to use another way instead dear. the `Robot` class would help you for controlling the remote machine.